# Making a list/vector of one column from different csv

Tags: r

I already loaded 20 csv files with function:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(tbl)) assign(tbl[i], read.csv(tbl[i]))
```

That how it looks like:

```
> head(tbl)
[1] "F1.csv"          "F10_noS3.csv"    "F11.csv"         "F12.csv"         "F12_noS7_S8.csv"
[6] "F13.csv"
```

In all of those csv files is a column called "Accession". I would like to make a list of all "names" inside those columns from each csv file. One big list.

Two problems:

- Some of those "names" are the same and I don't want to duplicate them
- Some of those "names" are ALMOST the same. The difference is that there is name and after become the dot and the numer.

Let me show you how it looks:

```
AT3G26450.1 <--
AT5G44520.2
AT4G24770.1
AT2G37220.2
AT3G02520.1
AT5G05270.1
AT1G32060.1
AT3G52380.1
AT2G43910.2
AT2G19760.1
AT3G26450.2 <--
```

`<--` = *Same sample, different names. Should be treated as one. So just ignore dot and a number after.*

Is it possible to do ?

I couldn't do a `dput(head)` because it's even too big data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first trick: you can read all the tables into a list of data frames using `lapply`.  This is easier to work with than 20 individual data frames.

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list_of_data = lapply(tbl, read.csv)
```

The second trick: you can recombine this list into a single data frame using `do.call` in conjunction with `rbind`.

```
all_data = do.call(rbind, list_of_data)
```

You can select the contents of the `Accession` field before the dot using regular expressions.  The `stringr` package is useful here. `^` represents the start of the string, `[[:alnum:]]` represents a letter or number (an alphanumeric character), and `+` means one or more.

```
library(stringr)
all_data$CleanedAccession = str_extract(all_data$Accession, "^[[:alnum:]]+")
```

Finally, you can remove duplicates by subsetting on non-`duplicated` values.

```
all_data = subset(all_data, !duplicated(CleanedAccession))
```

Comment: That code looks fine but the problem is that I can't use rbind because I have different number of columns/rows in each csv file. Any solution ?

Comment: @Rechlay: if the contents of each table represent the same sort of thing, you should combine them. (You can add dummy fields to make columns match.)  On the other hand, if they represent different things, then it is probably best to keep them as a list of data frames.  You can use `lapply` to loop over the list and update each data frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the list of names, and if they're all formatted as in your example, then using @Richie's all_data:

```
names <- unique(substr(all_data$Accession,0,9))
```

does it without regular expressions.